# usage of "$and" condition in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I tried to find out the id and name of those students that are not passed in the English exam on MongoDB, the grade shown Fail as "N", and Pass as "P".
I'm not sure whether I used the and statement right.

```
db.enrolment.find({$and:[{"Info.grade":"N"}}, {"Info.grade":{"P"}}}] },{"_id":1,"name":1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be not right. 
First - `"Info.grade":{"P"}` is not a valid syntax. It should be `"Info.grade": "P"`.
Second - You need to search for just a single condition, instead of double. So, your query would be something like this -

```
db.enrolment.find({
  "Info.grade":"N"
}, {
  "_id": 1,
  "name": 1
});
```